# Visual Studio design view is blank

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been using Visual Studio for 5 years. I have never used Design view. I am just starting a new, hobby, site and find myself using default.htm instead of .aspx as there will only be html.

I thought, for a laugh, I'd use Design view - as it's more intuitive to type our your text rather than endlessly doing it in the source view with all the tags to disrupt your creative juices.

But, when I click Design View, the screen is blank. There are tags across the bottom - html, body, topdiv, divcontainer etc. - but it doesn't matter what I click on, the screen is empty.

Click on source and all my carefully crafted text is there, click on Design and nothing is there.

So, I'm being thick - is there some trick to get Design view to actually show something?

Comment: Try adding something in Header and see if designer shows it.